# SSH on Ubuntu with Port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I am a newbie to networking, so need some help to understand if what I am doing is right:

I have a VM which hosts a Ubuntu guest OS with an internal IP: **192.168.15.6**
I have setup an ssh server on port **5022** (in case the ISP blocks 22).
I also have a web server (Apache 2) setup on port **8002** (in case the ISP blocks 80).

My external IP is: **xx.yy.aa.bb**.
I have configured my router to port forward port 8002, and now I am able  to acces my web server from an external box. But going by the same pattern, I port forwarded my ssh port as:

```
source ip: xx.yy.aa.bb
source netmask: 255.255.255.0

destination ip: 192.168.15.6
destination netmask: 255.255.255.255 (I cannot change this)

destination port start: 5022
destination port end: 5022
destination port map: 5022
```

I am still unable to access my ssh service from an external machine.

What am I missing?